# MoneroWorld Remote Nodes Not Working

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, mining, nodes, ports, firewall

I am mining Monero using Remote Nodes. To mine, I use the following command:

*sudo ./monero-wallet-cli --daemon-address eu.node.moneroworld.com:18089 --trusted-daemon*

The nodes are from moneroworld.com/#nodes

e.g.

geo.node.moneroworld.com at port 18089 - AUTOMATIC 
eu.node.moneroworld.com at port 18089 - Europe

When I run the "start_mining" command I get the following error:

```
Error: wallet failed to connect to daemon: eu.node.moneroworld.com:18089. Daemon either is not started or wrong port was passed. Please make sure daemon is running or change the daemon address using the 'set_daemon' command.
```

I have tried other addresses and still the same issue:

```
set_daemon geo.node.moneroworld.com:18089
start_mining
```

Result:

```
Error: wallet failed to connect to daemon: geo.node.moneroworld.com:18089. Daemon either is not started or wrong port was passed. Please make sure daemon is running or change the daemon address using the 'set_daemon' command.
[wallet 42X2yL]:
```

1. Is MoneroWorld dead? If so, is there alternative nodes that can be recommended?
   Alternative, if it is not dead:
2. Could this be a firewall/ports issue? If so, how do I explicitly open the standard ports required for Monero on Ubunto?

Comment: how or where do you use `set_daemon` and can that be "hard coded" somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. MoneroWorld is not dead.
2. Unlikely a ports issue, it's all outbound. You are connecting to it then trying to start_mining and herein lies your issue - you are trying to mine on a remote **public** node. Please see this [Q&A](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8670/monero-wallet-cli-remote-mining-intermittently-works).