# monero-wallet-cli Remote Mining Intermittently works

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, mining, nodes

I am mining Monero using Remote Nodes. To mine, I use the following command:

*sudo ./monero-wallet-cli --daemon-address eu.node.moneroworld.com:18089 --trusted-daemon*

The nodes are from moneroworld.com/#nodes

When I run the "start_mining" command sometimes it works, other times it says:

```
Error: wallet failed to connect to daemon: eu.node.moneroworld.com:18089. Daemon either is not started or wrong port was passed. Please make sure daemon is running or change the daemon address using the 'set_daemon' command.
```

Why is it so intermittent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Public remote nodes should not be used for mining. Remember the mining happens on the remote node, not your local machine, so you would be using precious resources of the remote public node. If it is your own private remote node, fine.

> Why is it so intermittent?

Probably because the remote node is stopping you, as it should, from leeching it's resources.